# What does this pink colour represent in my VScode Tree View

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

All the other colours are obvious because they seem to be Git related, but i cannot for the life of me figure out what this is, thanks.

Comment: Can you produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I can't get that colour to show up in my VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some files under node_modules have reported problem. Verify that using Problems Panel:

[image]

VS Code reports them as soon as you open file that contains errors.